# Spring - JMS , how to start JMS after application is up and continuously try to reconnect if it goes down

Tags: java, spring, spring-jms

I have spring application in which I am trying to connect to JMS activemq server. my context file content looks as below:

```
<bean id="amqPowerConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg index="0" value="${power.messagebrokerurl}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="powerConnectionFactory" class="org.springframework.jms.connection.CachingConnectionFactory">
    <constructor-arg ref="amqPowerConnectionFactory"/>
</bean>

<bean id="timeSeriesChangesContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="powerConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="powerEventQueue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="timeSeriesDataAdapter"/>
</bean>
```

But if the JMS server is down, then server does not initialize the spring context at the startup.

I can set autoStartup to false and then spring intializes the context, but then how do I start this listener manually ?

```
<bean id="timeSeriesChangesContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="powerConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="powerEventQueue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="timeSeriesDataAdapter"/>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="false"/>
</bean>
```

Also I need to code a continuous loop where it will try to re-connect to this JMS server if it goes down.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Message Listener has a function start().
With that function you can start the Listener manually in your program.

As for the loop: We had a similiar problem where we had to start and stop the listener at given times due to inavailability of system components and we realised it with scheduled jobs.

Below is an example for starting the listener through a scheduled job:

**Update:**

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class StartStopJmsBatch {

private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(StartStopJmsBatch.class);

@Autowired
private DefaultMessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer;

@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 * * * *")
public void startJmsConsumer() {
    if (!messageListenerContainer.isRunning()) {
        LOG.info("Started JmsListenerContainer");
        messageListenerContainer.start();
    }
}
}
```

I added the rest of the class.
It is scheduled with spring's scheduling mechanism ([take a look here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html) at chapter 28.4 especially)
as for the cron expression syntax [take a look here](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/support/CronSequenceGenerator.html)

**Alternative**

An alternative would be to use Spring's DefaultMessageListenerContainer ([take a look here](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/listener/DefaultMessageListenerContainer.html)) which has a self recovery function build in and which should initialize the spring context even if the JMS server isn't available at application start.

Comment: Thanks, Can you please give more details about (cron = "${cron.startjmsconsumer}")  and where are you writing this class (above code basically)

Comment: I updated the answer, please check if you need some more informations or if it is enough already

Comment: I copied your class and put in my workspace, keeping <property name="autoStartup" value="false"/> for the bean. Spring context initialized at the server startup. JMS server is still down. Now I starts JMS it and I was expecting it show me "Started JmsListenerContainer" info in the log,  but it did not. Am i still missing something ? any entry in the application context probably ?

Comment: I am still not sure (cron = "${cron.startjmsconsumer}") role ?

Comment: You need to add <task:annotation-driven> to your spring xml config (specified here http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html at chapter 28.4) and the ${cron.startjmsconsumer} is a placeholder replaced by spring in our project. In your case it should look like this: (cron = "0 0 * * * *") that expression will schedule the job to run at the top of every hour of every day (I exchanged the placeholder in the answer with an actual value to avoid further misunderstanding)

Comment: Looks like after adding <task:annotation-driven> in the config file, now I get this error " Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'startJmsConsumer': Could not resolve placeholder 'cron.startjmsconsumer' in string value "${cron.startjmsconsumer}", so as you said i should set it to  (cron = "0 0 * * * *")  ?? But i need our app to listen to JMS as soon as its up

Comment: if you set it to (cron = " */10 * * * * *") it will try to start the listener every 10 seconds if it's not already runing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83870/discussion-between-wuteb-and-sohan-soni).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @Wuteb for the answer, I finally switched from SimpleMessageListenerContainer to DefaultMessageListenerContainer as you said and then there is no need to add any class (i.e. StartStopJmsBatch As suggested above) and only piece that we have to add is

```
<bean id="timeSeriesChangesContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="powerConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="powerEventQueue"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="timeSeriesDataAdapter"/>
    <property name="recoveryInterval" value="500"/>
</bean>
```

where recoveryInterval specify the interval between recovery attempts, in milliseconds.

Comment: Just wanted to confirm, did recoveryInterval work for you even when JMS server was unavailable at the application startup. While going through the code 'DefaultMessageListenerContainer', doesn't seems to be implemented that way. Additionally, got the same confirmed from the reference link - http://zachxu.blogspot.com/2014/05/how-spring-defaultmessagelistenercontai.html (sec : Receiving messages using DefaultMessageListenerContainer). Currently my code activemq-all-5.3.0-jar and Spring 3.2.7, but am open to any upgrades, if that works. Any updates appreciated.